# Get structure and data from MySQL database and import into SQLite database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a program where I want to get data from my MySQL database online, get the sql to dump the table one by one, and then take the data dump and put it in a new SQLite database. Once the SQLite DB's are seen to exist, it won't run again, so I don't need to worry about file names etc.

Anyway, to my main question: How do I get a data dump from a MySQL database with C#, and dump it into an SQLite DB, structure included?

Cheers